# how to use opencv in android to process video in real time

Tags: android, opencv

well hello there i m a beginner to the opencv android world and i am developing an app using opencv from my understanding and reading i have so far understood that the onCameraFrame() function in the app works on each camera image frame which we can process and send some different output to the screen. I know its very basic question but is there a way i can iterate through this camera image frame like:

```
for(int i =  0 ; i < mat.rows()...){
    for(int j = 0 ; j < mat.cols()...){
           //my image processing
         }
     }
```

i have tried various methods such as :

```
double [] mpixel = mat.get(i,j);
```

but the app doesnot seem to work i am stuck it will be helpful thank you in advance :)

PS:

i am trying to extract the foreground from the video i am making an app which will be like an video call bt it will cut out the human from the video and send it to next part of my app which deals with it.
IN SHORT: I just need to extract the foreground human and the background will be mostly a white coloured wall.

UPDATE:

Tried using grabcut :

```
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    mrgba = new Mat(width , height , CvType.CV_8UC3);
    mfrg = new Mat();
    mbg = new Mat();
    mgrey = new Mat(width, height ,CvType.CV_8UC3 );
}

public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    mrgba.release();
}

public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

    mrgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mrgba , mgrey , Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2BGR);
    mmask = new Mat(mgrey.rows() , mgrey.cols() , CvType.CV_8UC1);

    Rect mrect = new Rect(100,100,100,100);



    Imgproc.grabCut(mgrey , mmask , mrect , mfrg , mbg , 1 );


    return mmask;


}
```

gives an  error the mask should contain only GC_BCD GC_FBD etc values

Comment: You can iterate the image that way, but I won't recommend you to do the same, leave that onto OpenCV, it will perform that job more efficiently. What operation are you trying to apply after iterating mat in that fashion ? maybe OpenCV already has an implementation for the same ?

Comment: hello sir thank you  for your reply i am trying to extract the foreground from the video 
i am making an app which will be like an video call bt it will cut out the human from the video and send it to next part of my app which deals with it..
IN SHORT: 
i just need to extract the foreground human and the background will be mostly a white coloured wall

Comment: The you can simply try threshold the image, it would be very fast and can be implemented in real time.

Comment: what if the background is not  white and the video is shot in a park or something  how to deal with that?

Comment: Then you need `cv::grabcut` algorithm

Comment: hello i tried an implementation of the grabcut solved many errors but failing to solve one of them i edited the question